# Laplace transform of multiple sources in a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, transient, laplace-transform

I came across this circuit and couldn't solve it. From what I know the Laplace transform of a DC source would be the constant divided by the \$s\$ variable. However, does this only applies to sources with a switch or all of the sources in the circuit like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For t < t0 = 0 sec, the reactive devices of the right circuit are all charged, so a possible equivalent circuit is the following. It allows us to determine the transient trend of voltages and currents when the switch is closed.

[image]